# creating file for every 24 hours depends on the timer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, timer

I have done like this...for executing backup(backup database Using mysql) function for every 24 hours scheduled at night 10 o clock

and it will check the file creation time(backup.sql) also (i.e),if there any file that was not created with in 24 hours it will creates the file .....that was done in backupdatabase function...

but it was not creating the file for every day at  night 10 o clock ....

I have used timer for creating  file on every day at night 10 o clock ...

and this is my code....

```
public partial class BackupForm : Form
{
 private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
 private Int32 _hours = 0;
 private Int32 _runAt = 10;

public BackupForm()
{
}
private void BackupForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _hours = (24 - (DateTime.Now.Hour + 1)) + _runAt;
  _timer = new Timer {Interval = _hours*60*60*1000};
  _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Tick);
  _timer.Start();


}

void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  string hostname = MainHelper.getServer();
  const string path = @"C:\folder\Access\backupdb\";
  var listfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\folder\Access\backupdb\", "backup-*.zip").OrderByDescending(File.GetCreationTime).ToList();
  var getfiles = new List<String>();
  var files = listfiles.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
  var dt = DateTime.Now;
  foreach(var file in files)
  {

    var creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(file);
    var diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(creationtime);
    if(diff.Hours > 24 && diff.Days < 2 && creationtime.Month == dt.Month && creationtime.Year == dt.Year && hostname == "localhost" && _hours == 24)
    {
      backupDatabase();// here, i am doing backup database(creating backup.Zip file) 

    }
    else if (_hours != 24)
    {
      _hours = 24;
    _timer.Interval = _hours * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I don't know where i did wrong ...

My aim is every day at given time a file is created(excutuion of backupdatabase function) and in addition to it has to check the file creation time (with in 24 hours)

would any one pls help on this..

any sample code would be very helpful to me for raising an event at particular time include checking 24 hours ......

Many thanks...In advance

Answer (score 2):

In your `Tick` event it looks like you need to `_timer.Stop()` at the start of that event and then `_timer.Start()` at the end to reset the timer.

**Edit:**

Step 1: in your `BackupForm_Load` event you can calculate the next occurrence of 10:00 am by doing the following:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var today = now.Date;
var tenAm = today.AddHours(10).AddDays(now.Hour >= 10 ? 1 : 0);

TimeSpan ts = tenAm - now;

var timeInMillisecondsTill10Am = ts.Milliseconds;
```

Step 2: in your `Tick` event call `_timer.Stop()` at the start of the event. Then set the interval to 24 hours hours from now which I've shown below. And finally call `_timer.Start()` just before the very last line of your `Tick` event to reset the timer:

```
var twentyFourHoursFromNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: do i need to place _timer.Stop() function before this event  _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Tick); ??????

Comment: @rockyashkumar First in your BackupForm_Load event calculate the time till 10 O'Clock from DateTime.Now. Then when the timer goes off and runs your Tick event, _timer.Stop() at the start of the event, set the timer to go off in 24 hours and then just before your closing } at the end of your event call _timer.Start() to reset the timer.

Comment: Many thanks ..... but would you pls show how "var twentyFourHoursFromNow" will related to tick event ...... would you pls show the code in tick event ...where i have to place that line ....

Comment: where i need to set the interval the interval to 24 hours hours from now...in tick event ....

Comment: got it but i need to check that in if condition how can i check if i check if i specified like the above...

Comment: @rockyashkumar What exactly do you want to check? Every time the Tick event fires it will have been 24 hours...except the first time.

Comment: along with that i need to check the file creation time also (that i have mentioned in my question) if any file is not created at the moment from (24 hours - time now) i want to execute the backup function ....this needs to be checked with tick event ( that i have done in if condition)...

Comment: @rockyashkumar My apologies, but I don't follow. Do you want to do a backup every 24 hours?

Comment: @rockyashkumar Every time your Tick event fires, you already know it has been 24 hours except for the first time it was run. Am I still missing something?

Comment: yaa , but i need to check the  file creation time with 24 hours  in addition to tick event 24 hours checking.....

Comment: @rockyashkumar Can I ask why?

Comment: i need to do back up every day ...with some conditions like ..if the back up file is not created in 24 hours then it will be created and i need to set the timer that will be at given time the file is created.... every day...

Comment: @rockyashkumar but the backup file will never have been created within 24 hours except the first time the program is run if your Tick event fires every 24 hours.

Comment: what i ahve to do , disabling the file creation time checking is the better option ??????

Comment: @rockyashkumar Sorry what do you mean by "disabling the file creation time checking is the better option"? As I understand it all you need to do in the tick event is stop the timer, set the interval to 24 hours, create a backup, and start the timer again. I don't quite understand the purpose of checking the file creation date/time?

Comment: Can you move this to a chat room now? @rockyashkumar can you stop adding `???????` to the end of every question, it's rude and that's how you quickly lose people's interest. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough @Kev i think this is done anyways. Good luck @rockyashkumar!

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel. You can use enterprise job scheduler like this one found at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net). Let Quartz.net handle the scheduling and firing the job on time. Invest your quality time in developing the business logic.

Comment: +1 for not reinventing stuff. If Quartz.net seems to complex for your needs, have a look at [NCron](http://code.google.com/p/ncron/) or what about the Windows Scheduler?

Comment: NCron looks like a better option. In my opinion Quartz.Net is a dumb port of Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
    void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
```

add `_timer.Stop();`

and before the method end  (before it's "}") 
add `_timer.Start();`

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like a task for a scripting language not a Forms app, but... you can really simplify your code if you use the Reactive Extensions library from Microsoft.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)).Subscribe(x => DoBackup());
```